# My Eclipse Mars won't refresh

Tags: java, eclipse

I updated to Eclipse Mars a few weeks ago and everything went well.  I only have a single non-eclipse plug-in which is Subclipse.

Today I added a few (java) files, and removed a few others, from the directories of an eclipse project (note: I didn't use eclipse to do this).  When I was done I refreshed the project and it gets stuck at 98% for a solid few minutes.

I was able to cancel the refresh so I tried a clean build and sure enough it reported the errors of the missing files but won't recognize the added files.  I tried a fresh again and it still hangs at 98%.  I've probably retried it 5 times now, and restarted eclipse several times, and every time is hangs at 98%.

Is there any kind of cache I can clear or something I can clean?  Maybe something else I can try?

EDIT/UPDATE: I just opened the project in my old Luna eclipse and it refreshed fine.  Note that it uses an entirely different workspace if that matters.

Comment: Have you checked the log files (if there are some)?

Comment: What OS are you on? Refreshes work just fine for me on Windows 7 Eclipse Mars. Also, what kind of project do you have? Java? Maven?

Comment: @tom: Checked the log file and nothing relevant seems to be in there.

Comment: @JasonThompson: This is on OSX.10, but not sure that would be related. This is a java project, but no ant involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it wasn't hung on refresh but actually doing a refresh and the progress bar was just inaccurate.

I do refreshes often and they usually take five seconds at most.  For some reason, something triggered my entire project directory to be rescanned.  Since I had thousands and thousands of data files in the project directory it was spending time looking at all of these.  Relocating them made the refresh snappy again.

So, no idea what triggered the full refresh, and no idea why the progress was so wrong, but it wasn't hung, just busy.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems using subclipse too. I changed to Subversive and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  For me, I can't even get Subversive to install and work so that's why I go with subclipse.  It's good to know, though, thanks!